Diophantine equation of order 2
Is this possible to provide full parametrization for the following Diophantine equation of order 2:
$2(a^2+b^2)=c^2+d^2$
as we can give all the solutions for:
$a^2+b^2=c^2$
as
$(a=m^2-n^2$,
$b=2mn$,
$c=m^2+n^2)$
It is stated that if you can find a non-trivial solution then you can find all solutions of Diophantine equations of order 2.
A non-trivial solution would be $(2,1,3,1)$.

Well known identity : $2(a^2+b^2)=(a+b)^2+(a-b)^2$  take $c= a+b$ & $d=a-b$

Definitely these are not all solutions. For example for some given (a,b) we may have multiple pairs (c,d). You did not understand my question.

Before asking any questions search it in Approach Zero website : https://approach0.xyz/search/
